# How to disable binded JQUERY event handler at a stage of code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm not well acquainted with JQUERY but I have a web app that pop-up a modal window when I double click a word on my html body. the problem is because the modal div is appednded to the html body when I also click on the modal the handler is executed and I want to disable it.

That is how I bind event handler:

```
$("body").bind('dblclick', function(e){ ...
```

and i want to disable it on here:

```
$('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup({        
        nOpen:function(){
```

Comment: Try `$("body").unbind`

Answer (score 2):

Just don't do anything in the click handler if the element which triggered the event is the popup:

```
$("body").bind('dblclick', function(e){
    if ($(e.target).closest('#element_to_pop_up').length) {
        return false;
    }
    //...
```

Comment: What if element inside `element_to_pop_up` is being clicked ?

Comment: @t.niese You're right. I was unsure and had to check the documentation first :)

Answer (score 1):

Better to use `on()` not `bind()` function:

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for
>   attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the
>   .bind() method is used for attaching an event handler directly to
>   elements.

See [Jquery On()](http://api.jquery.com/on/),[Jquery Off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

Thus,

```
$('element').on('dblclick', function(e){...});
```

`$('element').off()`  - will remove all event listeners from given element.
`$('element').off('dblclick')` - will remove only double click from given element

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`unbind()`](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) method:

```
$('#element_to_pop_up').bPopup({        
    nOpen:function(){
        $("body").unbind('dblclick');
    });
});
```

But keep in mind that you will have to bind it again when you close your popup, if you want it to work after the popup is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Try `unbind` an event like this:

```
$('body').unbind('dbclick');
```

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)